# How to get the standard hand cursor to appear over the Accordion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

What property do I need to set here ?

```
 <cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true" AutoSize="Fill"
                SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false" DataSourceID="objQues" TransitionDuration="250">
                <HeaderTemplate>

.
.
.
```

I tried this..not working:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function fnover(id)
    {
        document.getElementById("Accordion1").style.cursor = "pointer";
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `HeaderCssClass` property where you can specify a CSS selector that sets cursor to pointer:

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"...
```

and then in your stylesheet define it like so:

```
.accordionHeader {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is how you could add the break.. Just use the same accordionHeader class:

```
.accordionHeader {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding break tag just before accordian's header template ends..its not working

Comment: So, you want to add space between headers to separate different sections, correct?

Comment: I've updated the answer - not sure though if it solves your issue.. if not, please provide more details.

Comment: It did yes, thanks. Now there's another probelm. I need to set the height of the Content ie the Answers that are displayed when Accordian is expanded..What is happening is if answer is long, it displays scroll bars...I dont want that. I want 10 px gap between headers as well as between answer and the next header in the list. How do I do this?

Comment: For the scroll bar issue - did you try to set AutoSize="None"?